# can't get ruby 1.8.7 to work after installing 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, pik

I installed ruby 1.9.2 via one click installer on windows 7.

Now I have a gem that only runs on 1.8.7

So I installed Pik and am trying to get 1.8.7 working.

irb runs fine, but require does not.

For example if I do a gem list
it lists the gem in question
When I require the gem in irb it says no such file to load.

When I use Pik to switch back to 1.9.2 all is well (i.e. the gem loads)

I have tried loading the gems outside of pik and inside of pik.

here is my load path running under 1.8.7:

```
....>ruby -ve "puts $LOAD_PATH.inspect"
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i386-mingw32]
["C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8", "C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i386-ms
vcrt", "C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8", "
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i386-msvcrt", "C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/vendor_ru
by", "C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8", "C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32", "."]
```

I do not see Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8  on the path... perhaps that is the problem?  if so how do I fix it (I don't know how to change the load path) and does anybody know why pik is not working or what I could do to fix.

In the end, does anybody know just how to get rid of 1.9.2, and do a clean install of 1.8.7?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While RubyInstaller include RubyGems with the package, Ruby 1.8.x itself does not activate RubyGems by default like 1.9.1 and 1.9.2 do.

You need to `require "rubygems"` before doing require to any of the gems you want to load.

Since your script can work on both versions of Ruby, you can do something like this:

```
require "rubygems" unless defined?(Gem)
```

Which will enable RubyGems if is not defined (which is under Ruby 1.9.2)

Hope that helps.

Comment: That was it... thanks very much.  by the way doing a require of rubygems running under 1.9.2 doesn't seem to hurt anything, is the "unless defined?(Gem) really needed?